# how openlayer show lower resolution tiles at high zoom level

Tags: openlayers

Here's my situation：i have worldwide tiles level 0 to 7, and some key area tiles level bigger than 7.

```
map.addLayer(
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    minZoom: 0,
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    url: url
                })
            })
        )
```

the problem is, when the zoom level bigger than 7 at a key area, it shows like this:
[image]
what I expect is when the zoom level bigger than 7 at a key area, other areas can show lower resolution, not blank.
what should I do this right?

Answer (score 0):

If the "blank" area is due to transparancy in the tiles you could split the source into two layers.

```
map.addLayer(
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    minZoom: 0,
                    maxZoom: 7,
                    url: url
                })
            })
        )
map.addLayer(
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                minZoom: 8,
                source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                    minZoom: 8,
                    maxZoom: 18,
                    url: url
                })
            })
        )
```

If the tiles have a solid background colour where there is no coverage you would need to use ol.source.Raster or a postrender event to filter it out by setting the opacity of those pixels to 0.